# Restarting Apache from Django

Tags: django, apache

I need my Django app to be able to restart the Apache server running it. I'm using mod_python.

Which is the easiest way?

Comment: Is it because you'd like to reload your application sources?

Comment: you shouldn't be using mod_python any more, it's deprecated. Use mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this would be possible is if you gave your Django application root permissions, which is horribly unsafe. But, assuming that your app is running as root, you can run

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['/etc/init.d/apache2', 'restart'])
```

Or whatever command your distribution has for restarting Apache. If the Django app is not root, you may be able to run it with `sudo` using the [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) python library.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart')
child.expect('[sudo] password for .*:')
child.sendline(password)
child.interact()
```

Note that this way requires you to give the apache user the ability to run `sudo` which is also insecure. In general, I can't see a secure way to accomplish this.

Comment: Well it is possible to restrict sudo access to only running certain applications or scripts. But, all in all I'm guessing the OP is really trying to solve some underlying challenge using the wrong mechanism...

Comment: @andy Agreed - I'm pretty sure there is a better way to solve the underlying problem than restarting Apache.

Comment: @Zhehao: I believe you wanted to write: "subprocess.Popen(['/etc/init.d', 'apache2 restart'])"

Comment: I need to restart Apache to get rid of processes with cached translation files (gettext .mo files). When a user clicks save in Rosetta, Apache must restart, for translations to take effect right away. The only other way I have found is to either modify the gettext code of Django to disable caching (which I couldn't make work) or to use mod_wsgi. For reasons we will stick to mod_python for a while yet.

Comment: A side question is: Can the calling function tell whether Apache has indeed been restarted? If using Popen, is it proper to wait for the child process to terminate, and if the parent gets beyond that point, it means that Apache was not restarted?

Comment: Since the program is being run by apache as a child process, it will stop executing once apache shuts down.